# python-ThreadPoolExecutor why task in threadpool will be execute in sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
def m1():
    for i in range(1,10):
        print("m1 i="+str(i)+" \n")
        time.sleep(0.5)

def m2():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print("m2 i=" + str(i)+" \n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
def m3():
    for i in range(1,10):
        print("m3 i="+str(i)+" \n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as tp:
    tp.submit(m1())
    tp.submit(m2())
    tp.submit(m3())
```

I made a threadpool and submitted 3 tasks

Result:

```
m1 i=1 

m1 i=2 

m2 i=1 

m2 i=2 

m3 i=1 

m3 i=2
```

What confused me is that, although I use time.sleep(), the thread is not hang up. All tasks are executed by submit sequence.
Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function to the threadpool, without calling it:

```py
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as tp:
    tp.submit(m1)
    tp.submit(m2)
    tp.submit(m3)
```

In your case they get executed "on the spot" hence why their execution is sequential.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't hesitate validating my answer if you feel like it

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Learningisamess is correct, but I think you should hear it in more detail.

This is a function call:

```py
m1()
```

You probably already knew that. But maybe what you did not already know is that every function call is an *expression.* That is, a fragment of code that can be *evaluated* (i.e., it can be *executed* to yield a *value.*)

Here's another expression:

```py
a+3
```

It is composed of two *sub-expressions,* `a` and `3`. It is evaluated by first evaluating its sub-expressions, and then adding the two values together. The `a` is evaluated by fetching the value from a variable named "a," and the `3` is trivial--its value always is 3.

The arguments in a function call expression are sub-expressions too. So, `tp.submit(x)` first evaluates `x`, and then it passes that value to the `tp.submit` function.*

You wrote:

```py
tp.submit(m1())
```

That will first evaluate the subexpression, `m1()` by calling the `m1` function. Immediately. In the program's main thread. Whatever `m1()` returns becomes the value of the subexpression. Then finally, `tp.submit` will be called with whatever `m1()` returned.

`m1()` returns `None`. And `tp.submit(None)` essentially does nothing. In particular, it does *not* generate any kind of error. It's pretty much just ignored.

What you really wanted to do is what @Learningisamess said: Write `tp.submit(m1)` instead. `m1` is an expression whose value is the function itself, and `tp.submit(m1)` tells the thread pool to call that function *some time later, and in a different thread.*

---

* In fact, `tp`, and `tp.submit` also are sub-expressions of `tp.submit(x)`, but I'm not going to dive all the way to the bottom of *that* rabbit hole.

Comment: It works ! I need to learn more about python mechanism